# Regolith 1.6 (21.04) / Ubuntu 21.04 is taking too long to boot

Tags: kernel, boot, regolith

Dual booting Regolith 1.6 and Windows 11 on separate drives (windows ssd / regolith hdd). The total boot time from GRUB to entering the password is about 1m40s which seems a little high even for a HDD.

Command output:

- `inxi -Fxz`:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.11.0-49-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 Desktop: GNOME 
          Distro: Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop System: MSI product: MS-7A37 v: 1.0 serial: <filter> 
          Mobo: MSI model: B350M MORTAR (MS-7A37) v: 1.0 serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends 
          v: 1.MW date: 11/01/2021 
Battery:   Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech G604 Wireless Gaming Mouse 
          charge: 55% (should be ignored) status: Discharging 
CPU:       Info: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 1600X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen rev: 1 
          L2 cache: 3 MiB 
          flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 91204 
          Speed: 3800 MHz min/max: N/A Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3800 2: 3800 3: 3800 4: 3111 5: 3800 
          6: 3800 7: 3800 8: 3800 9: 3800 10: 3153 11: 3800 12: 3800 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: nvidia 
          v: 495.46 bus ID: 26:00.0 
          Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: nvidia resolution: 1: 1920x1080 
          2: 1920x1080~60Hz 3: 1080x1920~60Hz 
          OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 495.46 
          direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: NVIDIA GP106 High Definition Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel 
          v: kernel bus ID: 26:00.1 
          Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
          bus ID: 28:00.3 
          Device-3: Kingston HyperX SoloCast type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
          bus ID: 3-2:3 
          Device-4: C-Media Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A) type: USB 
          driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus ID: 1-5:2 
          Device-5: Logitech Webcam C270 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo bus ID: 1-6:3 
          Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-49-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Micro-Star MSI 
          driver: r8169 v: kernel port: f000 bus ID: 22:00.0 
          IF: enp34s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 3.17 TiB used: 381.22 GiB (11.8%) 
          ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37480G size: 447.13 GiB 
          ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: ST2000DM008-2FR102 size: 1.82 TiB 
          ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Seagate model: ST1000DM010-2EP102 size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 393.18 GiB used: 10.67 GiB (2.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdc2 
          ID-2: /boot/efi size: 335.7 MiB used: 32.3 MiB (9.6%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sda1 
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 29.34 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) dev: /dev/sdc3 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 44.9 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 58 C 
          Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 0% 
Info:      Processes: 313 Uptime: 33m Memory: 15.57 GiB used: 2.33 GiB (15.0%) Init: systemd 
          runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 10.3.0 clang: 12.0.0-3ubuntu1~21.04.2 Packages: 1641 
          Shell: Bash v: 5.1.4 inxi: 3.3.01
```

- `systemd-analyze`:

```
Startup finished in 18.473s (firmware) + 4.941s (loader) + 1min 9.059s (kernel) + 37.129s (userspace) = 2min 9.603s 
graphical.target reached after 37.124s in userspace
```

- `systemd-analyze blame | head -5`

```
30.145s udisks2.service
 7.706s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 4.216s networkd-dispatcher.service
 3.106s NetworkManager.service
 2.948s accounts-daemon.service
```

- `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @37.124s
└─udisks2.service @6.977s +30.145s
  └─dbus.socket @6.714s
    └─basic.target @6.714s
      └─sockets.target @6.714s
        └─uuidd.socket @6.714s
          └─sysinit.target @6.656s
            └─swap.target @6.656s
              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-628081aa\x2d21b7\x2d4ec7\x2d821f\x2dd6f61598b307.swap @6.470s +185ms
                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-628081aa\x2d21b7\x2d4ec7\x2d821f\x2dd6f61598b307.device @6.469s
```

- `blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL_FATBOOT="SYSTEM" LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="0A30-49D0" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="f40d85e0-0af4-4444-acdd-b2360bf3ff53"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="01D80A5E8CC8C0C0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="b7d369cd-24d2-4865-add7-fd2180184e98"
/dev/sda3: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="08B621A3B621926C" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="76907b38-167d-4f62-88af-88c16393922a"
/dev/sr0: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2020-08-13-18-34-00-0" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL_FATBOOT="EFI" LABEL="EFI" UUID="67E3-17ED" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="eca237fd-5708-468d-a539-6e750c598a48"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Games" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="86A9BF0D12EF743C" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="000004c1-6850-e4cf-37d7-d70182090000"
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="Software" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="01D83B0FE0F09100" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Software" PARTUUID="00000b39-17d0-e5cc-37d7-d77d72160000"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Media" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="01D85F413D9927F0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="0000007b-51e0-3d4d-415f-d801f6000000"
/dev/sdc2: UUID="4cf3641b-ffc4-41bf-9602-d093aa4c8684" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7f296866-6ba3-4c15-a265-47aefa7086ed"
/dev/sdc3: UUID="628081aa-21b7-4ec7-821f-d6f61598b307" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="dc63d6af-e6a4-4843-8e42-8ee63c578863"
/dev/sdc4: UUID="C4D3-E100" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="c8c8bed4-29ca-44db-a822-2565094fb27c"
```

- `cat /var/log/syslog` (lines with the biggest time differences)

```
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [    3.726308] input: Logitech G604  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.2/0003:046D:C539.000D/0003:046D:4085.000E/input/input30
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [    3.726414] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4085.000E: input,hidraw13: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech G604 ] on usb-0000:03:00.0-9/input2:1
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   34.365976] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   34.367804] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   59.694597] fbcon: Taking over console
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   59.694675] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.093961] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.096164] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.205957] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 23728 MB/s
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.273956] raid6: avx2x4   xor()  7558 MB/s
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.341956] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 26037 MB/s
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.409956] raid6: avx2x2   xor() 16538 MB/s
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.477956] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 23465 MB/s
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.545956] raid6: avx2x1   xor() 16198 MB/s
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.613955] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 15787 MB/s
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.681957] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  7991 MB/s
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.749955] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 17775 MB/s
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.817956] raid6: sse2x2   xor() 11033 MB/s
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.885956] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 13313 MB/s
May  5 12:13:14 vain-pc kernel: [   65.953956] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  9284 MB/s
```

Please let me know if there is any other info you would need from me. The only three partitions this linux install actually uses (from the `blkid`):

- `/dev/sdc2` - ext4 root
- `/dev/sdc3` - swap
- `/dev/sdc4` - fat32 EFI system

I am not sure if it's relevant but after I select the boot option from GRUB it black screens a bit and then most of the starting time is spent with the BIOS screen showing (but its not able to take the input from the  key to go into BIOS settings, so it is just the image).

EDIT: Command `sudo journalctl -xb -u udisks2` output:

```
-- Journal begins at Thu 2022-05-05 01:31:49 EEST, ends at Thu 2022-05-05 23:53:41 EEST. --
mai 05 23:42:06 vain-pc systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit udisks2.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit udisks2.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 150.
mai 05 23:42:06 vain-pc udisksd[891]: udisks daemon version 2.9.2 starting
mai 05 23:42:09 vain-pc udisksd[891]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared >
mai 05 23:42:09 vain-pc udisksd[891]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
mai 05 23:42:36 vain-pc systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit udisks2.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit udisks2.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 150.
mai 05 23:42:36 vain-pc udisksd[891]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
mai 05 23:42:36 vain-pc udisksd[891]: Cleaning up mount point /media/vain-dev/2020-08-13-18-34-00-0 (devic>
```

EDIT:

- contents of `udisks2.conf`

```
[udisks2]
modules=*
modules_load_preference=ondemand

[defaults]
encryption=luks1
```

Comment: ah it does detect a RAID controller and tries to load the right plugins, but fails at first. Then, some 30s of magic something happens! The fact that it tries to load the mdraid plugin on its own is interesting. Does that appear in /etc/udisks2/udisks2.conf ? does `modules_load_preference` say `ondemand` or `onstartup`?

Comment: added the contents of the conf file you mentioned. it says `ondemand`

Comment: huh, then it has a *reason* for trying to load the mdraid module it can't load! Is the `libblockdev-mdraid2` package installed? (`apt install libblockdev-mdraid2`)

Comment: it was not installed, installing it now. should I try a reboot and see how it goes?

Comment: I think that would be worth a try! At the very least, we hopefully are getting rid of a logged error :) (though the must of what we can shake off here is 30s; more time is spent in the kernel, which probably for some reason has a hard time initializing all hardware before handing over to userland, and I still feel like blaming your optical drive out of these having been the source of that at least 3 times in my own experience)

Comment: somehow it got an extra 1 second in kernel startup time

Comment: that might be variability due to hardware / external factors; the kernel startup time cannot be affected by files loaded later

Comment: I physically removed the SATA connector from the drive and now the 2m and something time has now been cut to around 47s (only 6s in kernel according to `systemd-analyze` :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a clue:

> 30.145s udisks2.service

Especially if this is what it seems to be:

> /dev/sr0: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2020-08-13-18-34-00-0" TYPE="iso9660"

You have a CDROM or DVD drive with a optical medium in there. It might simply take a lot of time to spin up. Try taking out the medium there, and you might save a lot of your udisk time.

It's also intriguing that your log tells you something about raid6, without you using RAID; do you maybe have some leftover RAID configuration?

Comment: I dont think I've ever used raid and this is a pretty fresh install so I'm not sure where it's coming from. I'll try removing the optical medium when i reboot into linux in a few.

Comment: you need to remove it *before* you boot.

Comment: is there anyway to simply tell the system to ignore it instead of physically removing it?

Comment: You might be able to disable the drive in the EFI setup.

Comment: I removed it physically for now but there was no change for the better. It was actually slower by a few seconds and just to be sure i checked `blkid` to verify that the optical medium is no longer there.

Comment: hm OK, that's surprising. Maybe can you really going into your EFI Setup thing and disable the DVD drive? Or even physically unplug it? Your 30s of `udisks2` are very unusual for such a system. Maybe `sudo journalctl -b -u udisks2` is also relevant.

Comment: its not exactly easy to physically unplug it since its an internal drive. what EFI setup thing are you reffering too? I am not sure how to disable it. I will add the output of the mentioned command in the original post.

Comment: EFI setup is this menu you get when you press a specific key at boot time, where you can do things like say from which devices to boot etc. In many EFI setup menus, you can also selectively disable SATA devices.

Comment: The RAID6 entries in the log aren't relevant - they're just what the kernel does when the mdadm raid module is loaded, it tries various parity algorithms to figure out which is fastest on the current CPU (which largely depends on what features the CPU has).

Comment: The only really interesting line in the kernel log was `ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps` - that indicates either a very slow/very old device (like a CD-ROM) or possibly a failing disk (or sata port or bad sata cable). From the OP's comments, it seems it was a CD-ROM or DVD drive, and the problem went away when it was unplugged. If an optical drive is needed in future, it would be best to replace it with an external USB model.